# htaccess - Redirect parent folder PHP script

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have this web api project which is developed by other company. The file structure is:

`/project
  ---/app
      ---/ApiEndpoint.php
  ---/public
      ---/index.php`

The **DocumentRoot** is pointing to `/project/public`. The **index.php** is working (http://myapi.com/), however when I try to browse into the api endpoint **http://myapi.com/api/endpoint** I got 404 error.

How do I configure the **.htaccess** to rewrite this condition?

**/project/public/.htaccess** config

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>`

Comment: What does your current config look like?

Comment: I added the current config.

Comment: `DocumentRoot` might be `/project` not `/project/public`

Answer (score 0):

The current configuration is there to make sure every request go to index.php (that is probably dispatching requests in some way) except for the files that actually are in the public directory (probably needed for static files like images, and such).

If you wrote a php yourself to be directly called by `http://myapi.com/api/endpoint`, you should put it in `/project/app/public/api/endpoint/index.php`.

BUT I suspect you should study that application more and understand the current dispatching method, before doing that.